# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot connect to paired bluetooth mouse after reboot

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, mouse

My laptop's wireless module `intel AX200`, which means it should be using the `iwlwifi-cc-46.ucode` firmware.
The mourse pairs and connects fine. However, it doesn't reconnect after reboot. Not even manually.
Here is my `dmesg` output

```
michael@GA401IV:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[    2.780171] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.780185] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.780191] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.780192] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.780195] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.792247] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.3 build 0 week 24 2017
[    2.794121] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 1
[    2.794123] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    2.794124] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    2.794124] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    2.794124] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    2.794125] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    2.812936] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
[    4.046995] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    4.047103] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1227296 usecs
[    4.047110] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    4.062101] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 14643 usecs
[    4.062553] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-20-1-3.ddc
[    4.065122] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send Intel_Write_DDC (-22)
[    4.074433] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 128 week 11 2020
[    4.636594] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.636595] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.636599] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   21.216811] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   21.216817] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   21.216822] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Here are some methods I have tried:

- setting `UserspaceHID=true` in `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf`
- installing `blueman` to let it manage my connections but that doesn't work.
- firmware update (I only updated one file though)

Also, I disabled secure boot. If that's relevant.