# Logitech K780 doesn't reconnect after reboot

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, bluetooth, wireless-keyboards

I have been unable to find this exact issue, but a similar one with no answers at [Ubuntu 20.04 cannot connect to paired bluetooth mouse after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292709/ubuntu-20-04-cannot-connect-to-paired-bluetooth-mouse-after-reboot)

After reboot, Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't automatically reconnect keyboard. Selecting "connect" it just spins and never connects. The only way I get it to work is by removing the device and re-adding it, then it works perfectly, until the next reboot.

Not sure what all is needed, but here is my output for `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
[    4.025351] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.025362] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.025363] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.025365] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.025367] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.048577] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 26 week 11 2020
[    4.694442] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.694445] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.694450] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    7.238314] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    7.238317] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    7.238319] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 2763.520290] hid-generic 0005:046D:B33B.0010: input,hidraw9: BLUETOOTH HID v0.29 Keyboard [Keyboard K780] on 04:d3:b0:cc:00:6e
[15815.762564] hid-generic 0005:046D:B33B.0011: input,hidraw9: BLUETOOTH HID v0.29 Keyboard [Keyboard K780] on 04:d3:b0:cc:00:6e
[16937.761068] hid-generic 0005:046D:B33B.0012: input,hidraw9: BLUETOOTH HID v0.29 Keyboard [Keyboard K780] on 04:d3:b0:cc:00:6e
[24610.784457] hid-generic 0005:046D:B33B.0013: input,hidraw9: BLUETOOTH HID v0.29 Keyboard [Keyboard K780] on 04:d3:b0:cc:00:6e
[57059.287394] hid-generic 0005:046D:B33B.0014
```

I do not have Blueman installed, not sure if that would even help as the above-referenced user had no success with similar issue for Bluetooth mouse.

Logitech forums have no such issue. Any advice would be helpful as I am able to connect by adding the device after each reboot, but it would be better if it automatically reconnected, even if just with the "connect" button.